# Java's Properties: differences between .propertyNames() and .stringPropertyNames()?

Tags: java

I have read [the javadoc of this class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) again and again, but still cannot figure out the difference.

Apart from the obvious difference that [`.propertyNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#propertyNames%28%29) returns an `Enumeration` and [`.stringPropertyNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#stringPropertyNames%28%29) returns a `Set`, as far as I can see, both methods return the same content. At least my musings say so.

Can the results ever differ between the contents returned by these methods? The only possibilities I see is that the second method, using an `Enumeration`, may return different results if the instance has been modified since `Properties` implements `Hashtable` which is fully synchronised. But apart from that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can the results ever differ between the contents returned by these methods?

Absolutely. From the docs:

> Properties whose key or value is not of type String are omitted.

`Properties` *extends* `Hashtable`, which was a dumb decision - but it means that you can write:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(new Object(), "Wow, a non-string key");
p.put("fred", new StringBuilder("Non-string value"));
```

The `stringPropertyNames()` method wouldn't return either of them, but `propertyNames()` would.

Comment: Hmm, OK, now say that I initiate a `Properties` from a property file (which is what I really do), can the result ever differ?

Comment: @fge: Quite possibly not. (They'd still need to be separate methods due to the different return types, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Uh, well, as is usual from you, you raise valid, obvious, undisputable points... I need to do some more tests here. It seems that Hashtable being threadsafe is only _part_ of the problem at hand... I wonder what the result will be if you try and "serialize" a Properties object when you have injected it with a key which is not a `String`, for one...

Comment: @fge: I'm not sure what the thread-safety issue you're thinking of is. But another point is that the enumeration and set implementations *may* behave differently if you add a new key while iterating over the results (quite possibly in the same thread).

Comment: Yes, obviously... I guess my question is a little too broad... In fact, I create a `Properties` instance "privately" and read from a properties file; my question was, really, is it ever possible that when reading from a properties file, the two methods may differ... I guess this sounds somewhat silly; but the Javadoc isn't crystal clear about that. I'll rephrase...